# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']. Nothing helps

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu, unix

I'm working on AWS (ubuntu server 18.04). 
When I try to run the code with " import numpy", I get an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I tried reinstall all libraries and have allready done all advices which was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859939/python-pandas-missing-required-dependencies-numpy-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220798/pandas-missing-required-dependencies-numpy):

```
sudo -H python3.7 -m pip uninstall numpy
sudo -H python3.7 -m pip uninstall pandas

sudo -H python3.7 -m pip install numpy
sudo -H python3.7 -m pip install pandas

sudo -H python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade numpy
sudo -H python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pandas

sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Note: doing `sudo -H python3.7 -m pip install numpy==10.14.0` I get an error.

Please, tell what can help in this situation else?

Comment: I think it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57756410/11669081. firstly download your package from https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files

Comment: All instruction? 1&2?

Comment: download the package from that link and follow the 2nd step to install i

Comment: Great. I've done it. New problem is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'.
should I repeat it with pandas?

Comment: yeah same as that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick Solution

```
pip uninstall pandas -y
pip uninstall numpy -y
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

Follow first uninstall and install it will works